# When does `mkdir -p /path/to/dir` exit with nonzero status?

Tags: mkdir

```
mkdir -p /path/to/something
```

when does the above command exit with nonzero exit status?

Does it happen, if and only if `/path/to/something` doesn't  exist as any file (or as a directory?) before running the command and the command fails to create it as a directory?

`man mkdir` says

```
   -p, --parents
          no error if existing, make parent directories as needed
```

Thanks.

Comment: Try `mkdir -p /dev/i/am/a/hacker` as non-root and see it fail. If you don't have permissions it will fail and return a non-zero value.

Answer (score 6):

To elaborate on the previous answer with a few examples.
It could be when trying to create folders inside system folders:

```
ubuntu:~$ mkdir /proc/test
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/proc/test’: No such file or directory
ubuntu:~$ mkdir -p /dev/null/test
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/dev/null’: Not a directory
```

Or when you don't have permission to the previous folder:

```
ubuntu:~$ mkdir -p /root/test
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/root’: Permission denied
```

It will also fail if there is a file by the same name in the folder:

```
ubuntu:~$ touch /tmp/test
ubuntu:~$ mkdir -p /tmp/test
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/tmp/test’: File exists
```

Answer (score 2):

From https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/mkdir-invocation.html#mkdir-invocation:

```
An exit status of zero indicates success, and a nonzero value indicates failure.
```

Failure is when the directories need to be created but the operation fails.